# Errors after rearranging pages into folders Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net, http-status-code-401

I had a c# application that was working perfectly until I rearranged the pages. 
I sorted it into folders. I ctrl+F each page and added the full path wherever there was a direct path.

Eg: ***DrugEntry.aspx*** with ***~/EntryPages/DrugEntry.aspx***

Even the master pages.

Now when I run, I have 2 problems.

1. My login page shows up fine. **When I click on a link that redirects**, it says:

> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required
>   to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to
>   the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory
>   or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's
>   administrator for additional assistance.

2.**It doesn't recognize any of the tags in the log4net webconfig anymore.**
Note: I have not moved/renamed webcongig or the log4net.dll

Comment: Check your folder property it's read only. so unchecked that property and it will resolve your first problem

Comment: But my Login page is in the same folder. How do I check my folder property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder with the inaccessible asp sheets had a webconfig file. I deleted the file. My code worked.